# How can I hook function exported by other dll which loaded by some dll?

Tags: c++, windows, hook

Process A loaded two dll-- dllA and dllB, dllB loaded another dll-- dllC. dllB use a function f import from dllC. My code in dllA, how can I hook the function f?  I don't know the name of dllB.

Comment: You can replace dllC with your own module that exports `f` and re-exports everything else from the original.

Comment: How to exports f in dllA? Can I exports a function which implement in other dll?